# Oracle - Counting timestamps where difference between timestamps greater than 1 hour

Tags: oracle

I have a worklog table that contains the following fields:

```
worklog_id,
agent_name,
ticket_number,
timestamp,
worklog_notes.
```

I would like to be able to count the number of worklog entries made where if the `agent_name`, `ticket_number` and `timestamp` (date) are the same the worklog entry is only counted if the time between the two entries is greater than 1 hour.

Example: John Smith make three worklog entries on ticket 12345.  The first timestamp is "10/11/2012 9:11:44 AM", the second timestamp is "10/11/2012 9:36:16 AM" and the third timestamp is "10/11/2012 11:18:20 AM".  In this example I would only want to give the agent credit for two worklog entries as the first two were less than an hour apart.

I've tried getting the logic to work using a "where" sub-query, but cannot get it working.  Would anyone have any example they could provide?  Thanks! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Does this get what you want?  The first entry by a given agent on a ticket should always be counted, and entries after that should only be counted if at least an hour has elapsed since the prior entry.

```
select agent_name, ticket_number, count(*) from (
  select agent_name, ticket_number, timestamp,
         lag(timestamp) over
            (partition by agent_name, ticket_number order by timestamp) prev_timestamp
  )
from worklog
where (prev_timestamp is null
       or (timestamp - prev_timestamp) >= interval '1' hour
      )
group by agent_name, ticket_number
```

I'm not sure this is exactly what you want -- if an agent keeps adding entries within an hour of the prior entry, none of them will be counted except the first.  So someone who adds a lot of updates gets penalized.

Maybe what you really want is to count the number of distinct hours in which an update was made:

```
select agent_name, ticket_number, count(distinct to_char(timestamp,'DD-MON-YYYY HH24')
  from worklog
  group by agent_name, ticket_number
```

Comment: Thanks a lot Dave!!  I went with the second query you provided and it worked like a champ!!  I have no clue why I never even thought of formatting the timestamp to achieve what I needed...I was going way too over the top and totally missed the simplest thing!! :)

Comment: [code]select agent "agent_name"
       ,sum(total_touches) "total_touches"
       ,sum(distinct_touches) "distinct_touches"

from (select a.agent_name as agent
             ,a.ticket_number as ticket_number
             ,count(a.worklog_id) as worklog_id
             ,count(distinct to_char(a.timstamp,'dd-mon-yyyy hh24')) as distinct_touches
      from worklog a
      where a.agent_name = 'john smith'
            and a.ticket_number = 123456
      group by a.agent_name,a.ticket_number)

group by agent[/code]